# Using Moment of Inertia Tensors to calculate the Rotation that has been applied to an object

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

A moment of inertia tensor $T$ can be rotated by a rotation matrix $R$ to $T'$ using $T' = RTR^{-1}$. If I know $T$ and $T'$, how can I find the rotation $R$ such that I can apply that rotation to another tensor $A$ to take it to $A' = RAR^{-1}$?

Basically, I am trying to use the moment of inertia tensor to find the rotation that has been applied to an object $T$ to apply the same rotation to another tensor quantity (in this case the Born Effective Charge) $A$ so that it is oriented correctly.

Comment: Your transformation property is wrong. This is the transformation for a linear transformation, not for a 2-tensor or quadratic form.

Comment: @TedShifrin - MMOI tensor does transform as indicated by op.

Comment: Oh. Because we’re doing specifically a rotation $R$, we have $R^{-1}=R^\top$. Apologies.

Comment: The problem can be stated as finding $R$ such that $$T'\,R = R\,T$$

Answer (score 0):

Given two MMOI tensor values measured at two different orientations (basis vectors), and assuming both are summed about the same point. Lets call the two tensors ${\bf T}_A$ and ${\bf T}_B$ for the two frames **A** and **B** and note that there exists a *unique* frame **C** such that ${\bf T}_C = {\rm diag}(I_1,I_2,I_3)$ designating the principal MMOI values.

<sub>I steer away from using apostrophes for designating frames as it confuses the notation.</sub>

Take each MMOI tensor and perform an eigenvalue decomposition to find the directions of the principal axis

$$ {\bf T}_A = {\rm R}_{C/A} {\bf T}_C {\rm R}_{C/A}^{-1} $$

where ${\rm R}_{C/A}$ designates the rotation of frame **C** with respect to **A**.

<sub>To make sure ${\rm R}_\ldots$ are rotations you have to enforce ${\rm R}^{-1} = {\rm R}^\intercal$ in the eigenvector decomposition process.</sub>

Similarly

$$ {\bf T}_B = {\rm R}_{C/B} {\bf T}_C {\rm R}_{C/B}^{-1} $$

where ${\rm R}_{C/B}$ designates the rotation of frame **C** with respect to **B**.

Now you are asked to find ${\rm R}_{A/B}$ such that ${\bf T}_B = {\rm R}_{A/B} {\bf T}_A {\rm R}_{A/B}^{-1}$ which is simply

$$ {\rm R}_{A/B} = {\rm R}_{C/A}^{-1} {\rm R}_{C/B}$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Should that last line be $R_{A/B} = R_{C/B}R^{-1}_{C/A}$?

Comment: Since we start in frame A, and we rotate from A to C ($R_{C/A}^{-1}$) then from C to B ($R_{C/B}$)

Comment: I thought I had it correctly, but you can try it out and see if I have it reversed. Remember to rotate from A to C you need $R_{C/A}$ and not $R_{C/A}^{-1}$.

Comment: I tried it out. Starting with a moment of inertia tensor $A$, I rotated it 180 degrees about the x axis with the standard rotation matrix $R_x$ to get $B = R_x A R_x^{-1}$. I then decomposed $A$ and $B$ to get $R_{C/A}$ and $R_{C/B}$. I used these to define $R = R_{C/B}R_{C/A}^{-1}$, and applied it to $A$ using $RAR^{-1}$ and got $B$. However, $R$ is not equal to $R_x$, and if I try to apply $R$ to another tensor, it does not apply a 180 degree rotation about the x axis.

Comment: I think it has something to do with how I am decomposing A and B. What is the proper way to construct $R_{C/A}$? I have just been using python's numpy.linalg.eigh (since moment of inertia tensors are symmetric). $R_{C/A}$ has det = 1 and follows $R_{C/A}^{-1} = R_{C/A}^T$, so these should be valid rotations.